# How do I create a file in subfolder of document directory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating one folder in document directory with name newFolder.So now i want to know how to create txt file in my folder which is create with newFolder i now how to create file in document directory but how to create file in my folder which is create by me.I want to fetch this file also from newFolder and pass to mail composer in iPhone.

**This is create folder in my document folder but now i want create file in this folder name newFolder help me in this.**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newFolder"];
    NSError *error = NULL;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
```

**i write this code but my csv file is create in doument diretory folder i want to cretae this file in my folder which is doument directory have with name newFolder**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *filename = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"EmployeeBase.Csv"]];
            NSError *error = NULL;
            BOOL written = [csvString writeToFile:filename atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
            if (!written)
                NSLog(@"write failed, error=%@", error);
```

Answer (score 15):

Here is an example of saving image in documents directory in your own folder...

```
UIImage *imageForShare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage.jpg"];
NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"New Folder"];
// New Folder is your folder name
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:stringPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:stringPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

NSString *fileName = [stringPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/image.jpg"];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageForShare, 1.0);
[data writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
```

**Swift 4.0 Version**

```
guard let image = UIImage(named: "anyImage.jpg") else {return}
guard var stringPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true).first else {return}
stringPath = stringPath + "New Folder"

// New Folder is your folder name
if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: stringPath) {
      do {
          try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: stringPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
      } catch let error {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
          return
      }
 }

 let fileName = stringPath + "/image.jpg"
 let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: fileName)
 if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {
      do {
            try data.write(to: url)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
       }
 }
```

Comment: This is working... But i am still searching for the one on how to create multiple sub folders inside documents directory and then save the images inside those sub folders.. Any help on this?

Comment: @PradeepReddyKypa Just do not append the extension and it will be a folder. You can also use `NSString *fileName = [stringPath stringByAppendingString:@"folderName/image.jpg"];`.

Answer (score 3):

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,    
    YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
    NSString *myPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MyDocuments"];

    //Create folder
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:myPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO 
    attributes:nil error:NULL];

    NSString *newStr=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Sample.txt"];
    NSString *filePath = [myPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:newStr]; //Add the file name
    [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a txt file (lets say file.txt) to a specific directory (lets say newFolder) like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newFolder"];
NSString *filePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];

NSString *str = @"THIS IS THE CONTENT OF THE TXT FILE";

[str writeToFile:filePath atomically:TRUE encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

I hope that helps ;)

Comment: This doesn't work. If you don't create the sub-folder in advance, `writeToFile` will not create it automatically and instead will return an error.